# SOLVED - Nvidia GPU 4K glitches on Linux Mint

Tags: graphics-card, linux-mint, resolution, gpu

I am experiencing graphical glitches when switching to 3840x2190. The GPU (below) supports the max resolution of 4096x2160, so if I switch to that resolution it looks just like 1920x1080 meaning that texts, icons, and windows look larger than on 3840x2160. Also, the GPU glitches are non existent on 1920x1080 resolution.

My questions are; does this GPU struggle to handle the two 4K resolutions (3840x2190 & 4096x2160)? Or is this a driver's issue?

Specs:

- i7-4790K
- 16GB RAM
- Evga Geforce Gt 740 4GB with driver v470.182.03
- 1TB SSD
- Vizio 4K TV 70in
- Linux Mint 21 (MATE)

**Replacing the GPU above with Nvidia GeForce GTX 770 2GB solved my issues.**

Comment: Verify your refresh rate isn’t exceeding 24 Hz, the problem, likely is the display.

Comment: - 3840x2190@24Hz = very low quality picture, very high choppiness on playback
- 3840x2190@60Hz = much better picture quality, almost no choppiness, so far no blinking.

Comment: Perhaps I spoke too soon! The blinking is back -_-

Comment: The specifications of your card only support 4096 x 2160 @ 24 Hz, these specifications, are on the Nvidia website. You’ll need to upgrade your GPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find anywhere the specs for this GPU that disclose the refresh rate. However, according to this [site](https://www.gpuzoo.com/GPU-EVGA/GeForce_GT_740_4GB_Superclocked_-_04G-P4-3748-KR.html), the `Maximum HDMI resolution:4096 x 2160 @ 24 Hz or 3840 x 2160 @ 30 Hz`. Unfortunately, this GPU isn't cable of running the preferred settings, so it'll stay at `1920x1080@60Hz` until I get a better card.

**Replacing the GPU above (OP) with Nvidia GeForce GTX 770 2GB solved my issues.**